# Exporting from Excel to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, excel

I am having some problems exporting from Excel to Arc.

Exporting directly from .xlsx to Arc

- columns such as Name and latitude disappears all together

Exporting from .xlsx to CSV, then erasing formatting, then exporting to Arc

- large numbers such as ones with 9 or more digits fail to display

Does anyone know a failsafe procedure to follow when exporting tables from excel to ArcMap 10.2 so that ArcMap retains all values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recently been having issues with the excel-table conversions.  I then attempted to save my workbook as a csv and create a feature class from XY table.  No dice there either.  With all else not working I came up with a round-about route that works every time.

- export csv file to a gdb.
- display XY data
- export events to create a permanent layer

Its still easy, but its an extra step.  The layer can then be exported to a shapefile if needed.